# Why I can't get the value from map function and use it outside?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, dictionary, return-value

I'm bulding a receipes app for practising, using spoonicular api. I'm stuck trying to display favourites recipes saved on local storage.

I have an array of ids saved in localstorage and Everytime i add a receipe i want to call api and display on screen. To do that I map over the array and get the object but I can't use the data outside map function. here the code
thank you if someone can help

```
const getMyList = () => {

          fav.map(async(id) => {
            try{
              const {data:res} = await axios.get(url)
              return res

              console.log(res)
            } 
            catch(error) {
              console.log(error)
            } 

            })

            setNewArr([...newArr, res])

      }
      useEffect(() => {
          getMyList()
        },[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Map is a way to mutate the contents of a array and returns a new array.

```js
const newArray = oldArray.map((item) => item )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const aData = fav.map((id) => axios.get(url)
  .then(r => r.data)
  .catch(e => console.log(e));

Promise.all(aData)
  then((data) => {
    setNewArr(prev => data.reduce((val, item) => ([...val, ...item]), prev));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

using Promise.all should help.
the function needs to wait for all api calls to finish or updated state when individual response is received

```
const getMyList = async () => {
    try {
         const promises = fav.map(async(id) => { return axios.get(url)})

         const res = Promise.all(promises)

         const mappedRes = res?.map(r => r.data) ?? []

         setNewArr([...newArr, ...mappedRes ])
     } catch (error) {
          console.error('error fetching, error)
     }
}
```

More about [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Hope it helps

Comment: i tried everything but nothing worked.. i think i will change road and try with useContext hook to display on favourite page.  each time i felt so close but then nothing :( thank youuu

Comment: Welcome, it will be easy for us to  help/guide you, if we could check a miminal reproducible example in codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
const getMyList = () => {
    let resArray = fav.map(async(id) => {
                try{
                  const res = await axios.get(url)
                  return res.data
    
                  console.log(res)
                } 
                catch(error) {
                  console.log(error)
                } 
    
                })
    
                setNewArr([...newArr, ...resArray])
    
          }
          useEffect(() => {
              getMyList()
            },[]);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).